# Excel search cannot find specific data in a worksheet, even when data exists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search

I have text data in two workbooks in Excel. The first problem is that when I search for text in any of the workbooks, the search does not work for some text. So for example, in the first workbook, I have the text "MTM SJ" in one of the cells. However when I search the workbook for the text MTM SJ, it says "We couldn't find what you were looking for. Click Options for more ways to search." This error only appears for some text. So, for example, in other cells I have the text "MMI SJ" and when I search for MMI SJ, it takes me directly to the cell. I have already checked to ensure that there are no spaces before or after the text in the cells.

The second problem may be linked to the first problem. When I do a vlookup of some of the text which is in the first workbook, and try to find that text in the second workbook, the vlookup fails. Again, it is only on the text/cells mentioned earlier (MTM SJ).

Please help to fix this, why isn't Excel picking up some text/cells?

Comment: It would help to get some sample data. If Excel tells you it can't find the value, it simply isn't there even though it appears to be there. You sure that there are no double spaces in between the words, or unprintable chars? Even linefeed characters will throw these formulas of.

Comment: Select this fragment ("MTM SJ") in the cell's value and copy-paste it into the search box. Does it cannot be found again? Cut and re-type this fragment in cell's text. Does it cannot be found again?

Comment: And what search options are you using?

Comment: Any blanks in cell? How did you search? Could you provide the sample file about your problem?